# Wolfenstein Enemy Territory stuttery screen anything under 125 fps

Tags: technical-issues, wolfenstein-et

It's frustrating that I can't play this old game on a good pc on 76 or 71 fps, which have reduced recoil and a more stable network connection.

Instead I have to play at 125 fps and mouse has to be set to 1000hz polling, otherwise moving mouse left/right shows a stuttery screen update. I have good hardware snd have optimized windows 7 and bios but nothing helps.

I have all the basics covered, so don't suggest updating drivers.

- The stutter is not network related as hosting own game foes the same. I've turned off all mobo, gpu, network, win7 throttling and power saving features.
- I've set nvidia inspector extension limit to 4844. On nvidia control panel performance single display, disabled threaded optimization, maximum 1 pre-rendered frames.
- my gtx 770 is barely getting used, around 7%. Running the game on single core or all four or changing priority has no effect on the stutter.
- I've done the acceleration mousefix, changed gpu snd soundcard to use MSI style interrupts.
- Have very low DPC and no bottlenecks that I can see wigh hwinfo snd riva tuner.
- Have 144hz LCD monitor.
- Running the ZXR soundcard in direct mode with matching bitrate to game (44.1khz) to prevent any latency.

Funny thing is had the same exactly problem show up on a prior computer with AMD hardware. Running the game from SSD drive.

Anyone familiar with this specific problem in this old game, please help. All my cvars and PB are fully optimized. Even when I run the game at 125 fps or even 250 fps, during online play there's sometimes missing intervals of time during which I get killed.

I'm fairly OK skillwise so that's not it. I think this microfreezes are related to the screen stutter at lower (76 fps) setting. I tried framerate capping and fps is rock steady even at 250 fps.

Comment: Dude, format that wall of text and make it straight to the point. It is barely readable...

Comment: I don't think you should play with this game, it is too old. I tried it too, without success. I have FPS drops with GTX 750 Ti, which is very funny (tbh not so funny). I should have 1000 FPS with this video card instead of 60 sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

Your monitor refresh rate and in-game refresh differ.  This causes your screen to not display all the frames.  Try setting your /r_displayrefresh to 144.  You won't get the spread advantage then, but your game will run much smoother.